# formatGMT YYYY returning next year and yyyy returning this year?

Tags: apex, datetime, date, formatting

We noticed a behavior with **formatGmt** function especially around using **YYYY** vs **yyyy**, anyone facing the same?

Below is showing one year ahead:

```
system.debug('GMT Time'+System.now().formatGmt('E, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z'));
```

The above code worked perfectly till last week, starting today or over the weekend above code started to return **2021** for **YYYY**, when we replaced **YYYY** to **yyyy** (ie below code) it's returning 2020 ie showing current year

```
system.debug('GMT Time'+System.now().formatGmt('E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z'));
```

Comment: Exactly, I'm facing the same issue. It's very weird, confusing and not documented anywhere in Salesforce. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

YYYY is week based calendar.

yyyy is our ordinary calender.

This is not SF behavior. but something expected whenever you use yyyy or YYYY as they are derived from java SimpleDateFormat.

Even SF [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)  points to refer [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Here is an excellent [blog post](http://dangoldin.com/2019/01/06/javas-simpledateformat-yyyy-vs-yyyy/) showing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, Pranay, we figured it out the moment we posted the question. Appreciate your prompt answer though.

Answer (score 4):

Got the answer

- y return year of the era
- Y returns week year

so in this last week of Dec when a/few day(s) of the week is/are of next year, **YYYY** will return **2021** (ie week year) and **yyyy** (as always) will return current year ie **2020**.

In short, if you are looking for the current year always use **yyyy** and **not** **YYYY** else these dec boundary weeks will trouble you; as it did to me.